# Rails 5 Strong Parameters not permitting main model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

This is driving me batty.

I have a relatively straightforward setup, but for some reason the main model I'm trying to pass is unpermitted.

The log looks like this:

```
Started POST "/statements" for ::1 at 2019-12-05 23:19:37 +1300
Processing by StatementsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"O4Ye+SFx7kGUceDKJlXs8A0FlH/e7r08xpLpDuICHmgAqaxw/e0UV8AR1pUZGhGlWKOcePtt3LXM7rsXXNTbGw==", "statement"=>{"content"=>"…all people are created equal.", "tags"=>"politics, equality", "parent_id"=>"dagCzw"}, "commit"=>"Submit variant and agree"}
Unpermitted parameters: :authenticity_token, :statement
```

Where `statement` is the one thing I'm trying to make -- but it's not permitted, and the created statement is always filled with nil attributes.

Thank you for any help with this!

Cutting out the hopefully irrelevant bits:

#### statement.rb

```
class Statement < ApplicationRecord
```

#### new.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "statements/partials/new_statement_form",
      locals: {statement: @statement, parent: @parent} %>
```

#### _new_statement_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(statement) do |f| %>
```

#### statements_controller.rb

```
  def new
    Rails.logger.debug "\n\n-------- new ---------\n\n"
    @statement = Statement.new
    @content = "…"
    if params[:parent].present?
      @parent = Statement.find_by_hashid(params[:parent])
      @content += "#{@parent.content}."
    end
  end

.
.
.

  def create
    if create_params[:parent_id]
      Rails.logger.debug "\n\nCreate child\n\n"
      @statement = Statement.find_by_hashid(create_params[:parent_id]).children.create(create_params[:statement])
    else
      Rails.logger.debug "\n\nCreate root\n\n"
      @statement = Statement.new(create_params[:statement])
    end
.
.
.
  def create_params
    params.require(:statement).permit(:content, :tags, :parent_id)
  end
```

Comment: It should be `children.create(create_params)`, I guess.

Comment: @MarekLipka yep, I caught that -- but it still doesn't change the fact that the statement isn't being permitted. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, what does 'it doesn't work' mean exactly? Does it throw an error?

Comment: We can't see your model associations but it looks like the problem may be with `@statement = Statement.find_by_hashid(create_params[:parent_id]).children.create(create_params[:statement])`. Have a read through the official guide to nested associations and see if that helps. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, user error.

The bug was actually in the name of an attribute -- in the form it should have been `tag_list` not `tags`, in order for nested attributes to work correctly.

I was mis-reading the line `Unpermitted parameters: :authenticity_token, :statement` as definite -- I guess the whitelisting happens after that log line.

Thank you all for your questions and help.